# ¿Qué hace exactamente git remote -v?

Tags: git

Veo que este comando con la opción -v muestra lo que hay en el remote origin, ¿hace algo más?

La referencia de Git no me ha dejado claro su funcionamiento.

`git remote -v`

Answer (score 0):

En el manual encuentras una descripción del comando:

```
man git remote
```

`git remote` sirve para configurar los repositorios que sigues. La opción `-v`
especifica el argumento "verbose" para mostrar la url del repositorio después del nombre de dicho repositorio: "git remote [-v | --verbose]"